# How can primary keys be updated?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, primary-key

I have a MySQL Database with the table:

```
user
----
id (PRIMARY KEY)
name
```

Let's for example say it's filled with:

```
id            name
--------------------
1             Monkey
2             Lion
3             Rabbit
```

Now I want to increase all id's by one, I'd do this with:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `id` = `id` + 1;
```

Theoretically this should work, because all entries get updated in the end.
However, the DBMS handles it by updating them in sequence which results in the error:

```
Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Is there any way to avoid getting duplicate key entries while updating a key?

Comment: have you tried change command?

Comment: Any particular reason to keep the order? Why not just `UPDATE user SET id=4 WHERE id=1`? Either way, auto increment may give you problems unless you update the next id it will generate.

Comment: How about `UPDATE ... ORDER BY id DESC`?

Comment: What is the reason to change `PK`.

Comment: You would never want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY id DESC`

```
UPDATE `user` SET `id` = `id` + 1
ORDER BY id DESC
;
```

### [Before update](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdfbbd/1)

### [After update](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d2e5/1)

Answer (score 0):

you need to drop primary key

```
   alter table xx drop primary key
```

and then update your table

and then add primary key

```
   ALTER TABLE xx ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id)
```

**EDIT:**

or you can add certain number which will not exist in your table lets say you add 10

```
  UPDATE `user` SET `id` = `id` + 10
```

[first](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5ee6b/1)

then -9

```
  UPDATE `user` SET `id` = `id` -9
```

[second](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b904f/1)